# Javascript not enabled when I use Selenium with Python and Geckodriver on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, raspberry-pi, geckodriver

I have been trying to automate a task with Python and Selenium on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with much difficulty. From what I can see everything seems to be working correctly apart from the fact that when I make a request to return the HTML, it appears as if Javascript is not enabled, giving me the message:

```
JavaScript is required. This web browser does not support JavaScript or JavaScript in this webbrowser is not enabled.

To find out if your web browser supports JavaScript or to enable JavaScript, see web browser help
```

My Python script looks like this:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import time

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()

username = "EMAIL_HERE"
password = "PASSWORD_HERE"

driver_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver_options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=driver_options)

driver.set_window_size(1366, 768)

driver.get('WEBSITEURL')

driver.set_script_timeout(30)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

print(driver.page_source)

#login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton')
#username_input  = driver.find_element_by_id('userNameInput')
#user_password_input = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordInput')

#username_input.send_keys(username)
#user_password_input.send_keys(password)

#login_button.click()

print("Successful!")

print("Quitting driver")
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

Is this correct? Or do I need to add some sort of 'Javascript enabled' tag when initialising the Webdriver?

Any help will be much appreciated, I've spent far too long trying to figure this out :)